# How to link a main.css to all Django templates?

Tags: python, css, django

I want to be able to call classes in my main.css from all templates I have in Django. Currently, I have it stored in app_name/static/css/main.css. How do I link this to the templates so that I can simply add a class to an html element and have the class apply?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a base template containing all your common stuff (JQuery, main.css).

So, you will have a template called `base.html` will **all** the basic stuff and placeholders for specific pages content:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/css/main.css">
    {% block additional_header %}
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Then, your **actual** page will be a template with something like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
This is specific content for your page
{% endblock %}
```

[Checkout Django's official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/). Look for the section titled `Template Inheritance`.